# Zeppelin Helium Application watch AngularObject

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to listen to frontend events (onclick/onchange) from a Helium Application?

I seem to be unable to use Angular in the Helium Appplication as I would within a Zeppelin notebook e.g.:

```
import org.apache.zeppelin.display.angular.paragraphscope._
import AngularElem._ 
...

<div><div>.model("myModel").display
...

AngularModel("myModel", "newValue")
```

because calling either gets me a null pointer exception (taken from the logs):

```
ERROR [2017-03-19 12:23:16,231] ({pool-1-thread-1} HeliumApplicationFactory.java[run]:283) - java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.zeppelin.helium.ApplicationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.helium.HeliumApplicationFactory$RunApplication.run(HeliumApplicationFactory.java:321)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.helium.HeliumApplicationFactory$RunApplication.run(HeliumApplicationFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.helium.HeliumApplicationFactory$LoadApplication.run(HeliumApplicationFactory.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I understand this is experimental but it'd be cool to have.

Thanks.